# sed replace - replacing text in bunch of files

Tags: sed

How to parse bunch of files and replace each occurance of __esct function?

```
__esct('Full name')
```

convert to:

```
$this->escape($this->translate('Full name'))
```

How to add that second brace after replaced text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this :

```
sed 's@__esct(\(.*)\)@$this->escape($this->translate(\1)@'  file.txt
```

Comment: Won't work, missing the final `)`

Comment: post edited accordingly =)

Comment: It will now cause an extra `)` to appear :) I think you mean `(\(.*\))` like in my answer.

Comment: 2 opening `(`, 2 closing `)`

Comment: Thank you. worked like a charm! (can't upvote without 15 reputation apparently)

Comment: @sputnick, right, 2 opening “(”, 2 closing “)”, but you escaped the opening “(” of the inner pair and the closing “)” of the outer pair.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's/__esct(\(.*\))/$this->escape($this->translate(\1))/'
```

Should get you a long way. It'll fail if you have `foo(__esct('Some text'))`

```
sed -e 's/__esct(\([^(]*\))/$this->escape($this->translate(\1))/'
```

This one will work for those, but fail for `__esct(foo('Some text'))`

Comment: did you forget the final forward slash?

Comment: Yup, edited to fix.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I can only select one though and sputnick was itty-bitty faster:)

Comment: No worries, use whatever works :)

Answer (score -1):

Perl has nice extensions to do something like that:

```
perl -pi -e 's;__esct\(\'([a-zA-Z ]*)\'\);\$this->escape\(\$this->translate\(\'\1\'));g'  list of the files to mangle
```

It will leave the originals as <file>.bak. This is just a global replace on each line, just as you'd write it in vi(1). In Perl, () and such are metacharacters, to match them you need \( \).

[I'm not 100% sure of the handling of the ', need to check what your particular shell does in such a case.]